# Calculate the sum over a list of minima of two vectors

Tags: python, performance, mathematics, numpy

I have the [following metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2409553/6876):

```
def d(x, y):
    """The metric."""
    return 1 - sum(min(xi, yi) for xi, yi in zip(x, y))
```

where `x` and `y` are numpy arrays of equal length (~3000). I know that the elements of x and the elements of y each sum up to 1 and are non-negative.

Can this be calculated faster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minimum calculation could be vectorized:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x, y):
    return 1 - np.minimum(x, y).sum()
```